# CompletableFuture promises & Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, completable-future

I'm using a service that gives me back a CompletableFuture promise, the thing is, i can only access its methods through reflection which is working just fine.
But treating the return of the promise is leaving me puzzled.

Normally one would use something like this to work with a CompletableFuture:

```
promise.thenApply(returnValue -> {
                //do something with it
             });
```

How would one do that with reflection?

```
promise.getClass()
                .getMethod("thenApply", ??)
                .invoke(retorno, ??);
```

Basically i want to pass a Lambda function to treat the returning of my promise but i'm unsure on how to do it and if it's possible to do it.

Comment: Why are you using reflection instead of a regular method call? And why are you doing that on the Future instead of its result?

Comment: Because the classes that i'm using are loaded by another class loader in an OSGI context, therefore i cannot have direct access to them.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is part of the JDK so it should be loaded by the same parent classloader. You should thus be able to cast your `promise` to `CompletableFuture<?>` and call `thenApply()` on it, with reflection inside the passed-in `Function` if needed.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of naive of me to think that this class would be loaded by two different classloaders, This worked thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompletableFuture` is part of the JDK so it will be loaded by the same parent classloader.

You should thus be able to cast your promise to `CompletableFuture<?>` and call `thenApply()` on it, with reflection inside the passed-in `Function` if needed.